# Вывести тип, использованный в шаблонных параметрах аргумента

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы тип `CharT` выводился автоматически в C++17?

```
template<typename CharT>
void test(std::basic_string_view<CharT> string) {

}
test<char>("hello world"); //ok
test("hello world"); //compile error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно добавить перегрузку:

```
template<typename CharT, ::std::size_t x_array_size>
void test(CharT const ( & string )[x_array_size]) {
    return test(std::basic_string_view<CharT>{string});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Сразу создавать `basic_string_view` через пользовательский литерал

```
using namespace std::string_view_literals;
test("hello world"sv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Присвойте тип по умолчанию:

```
template<typename CharT = char>
void test(std::basic_string_view<CharT> string)
```

Тогда если вы явно не укажете тип для шаблонной функции, будет использован `char` по умолчанию

Comment: А как тогда быть с test(L"hello world"), test(u"hello world"), test(U"hello world")?

Comment: @EgorMoroz компилятор - не телепат!!! Он не может знать, какой тип вы там хотели вывести. Для этого, собственно, и существуют такие понятия как шаблоны и специализация.

Answer (score 0):

Извините, но мне не совсем понятно, зачем Вам это нужно. Вам не нужен никакой вывод типов для того случая, который Вы описали:

```
test<char>("hello world"); //ok
test("hello world"); //compile error
```

Функция, которая в качестве параметра принимает `std::string_view` прекрасно справится и с `std::string`, и с C-string:

```
void print_str_view(std::string_view str_view) {
    std::cout << str_view << std::endl;
}

const char* str0 = "C-string";
std::string str1 = "std::string";

print_str_view("string");
print_str_view(str0);
print_str_view(str1);
```

А вот если Вы передадите в качестве аргумента `std::wstring` - код не скомпилируется. Эту проблему решит перегрузка вышеуказонной ф-ии функцией:

```
void print_str_view(std::wstring_view str_view) {
    std::wcout << str_view << std::endl;
}
```

Пример:

```
std::wstring str2 = L"légo";
print_str_view(str2);
```